# How to connect Azure batch from Azure data factory through a private link?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-batch

I have a azure batch account with **only selected network** option enabled. So how do i connect to this batch account from my azure data factory? Through private link? if so how do i do this because i am not finding a managed private endpoint option for batch service in ADF

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use a [self hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime) as seen in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=weiHOeje-QA) (I am not affiliated in any way with that video, I just found it while searching solutions to connect to private resources from ADF)

So create a private endpoint for your batch account and create a Self Hosted IR for your ADF in a Vnet that can access the private endpoint and this will allow your ADF to communicate with the Batch Account.

Unfortunately the Self Hosted IR can only be installed in windows machines and it requires relatively high resources (4 cpu / 8 ram) so a VM to host it would be costly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. but i have already tried this.. the limitation is the number of parallel external connection using a self hosted IR is limited based on the VM size... since i need to scale my batch jobs to large extent this is not a feasible solution in my case.. i need to use a very large VM just to schedule many jobs in batch

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported by ADF. You can create an idea for it here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c